# namespace but is used like a type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, clean-architecture

I have try to add a customer class to my project and I see error "namespace but is used like a type"

I have tried to read the same question and I have try to modify the namespace and i get more errors.

As you can see in my github at https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/Bulky_MVC/commits/master

In Models Project I have name space

```
namespace BulkyBook.Models.Models
{
    //https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-core/
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And In Web Project I have name space, I want all Customer can view the page. Not in the Admin Area.

```
namespace BulkyBook.Web.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Area("Customer")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public CustomerController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        // GET: CustomerController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Customer> objCustomerList = _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(objCustomerList);
        }

        // GET: CustomerController/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: CustomerController/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CustomerController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CustomerController/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CustomerController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CustomerController/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CustomerController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```